# Hard drives added to fstab not mounting at startup – Pop-OS 20.04

Tags: mount, startup, fstab

I added three drives to the `fstab` file following a tutorial but only one of them mounts at startup. I tried `sudo mount -a` and all three drives mounted.

`fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>  <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=b964dcd3-f8cf-45e4-b903-a90febb29195  /  ext4
noatime,errors=remount-ro  0  0
PARTUUID=bdc5a06f-06c7-4b1c-bf9e-e8770d24ce87  /boot/efi  vfat
umask=0077  0  0
UUID=B28691348690F9D5   /media/data ntfs    defaults    0 0
UUID=228C52CC8C5299DD   /media/data ntfs    defaults    0 0
UUID=40D6A802D6A7F676   /media/data ntfs    defaults    0 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mounting all three NTFS partitions to the same mount point (`/media/data`). You probably want to modify the entries in your `/etc/fstab` like so:

```
UUID=B28691348690F9D5   /media/data1 ntfs    defaults    0 0
UUID=228C52CC8C5299DD   /media/data2 ntfs    defaults    0 0
UUID=40D6A802D6A7F676   /media/data3 ntfs    defaults    0 0
```

Don't forget to create the mount points (`sudo mkdir /media/data{1..3}`) before running `sudo mount -a`.